# Java 3D ERROR : OpenGL 1.2 or better is required (GL_VERSION=1.1)

Tags: 3d

how to fix this problem please? I found something about new drivers for my graphics card but its not working. My driver is up to date.

```
javax.media.j3d.IllegalRenderingStateException: GL_VERSION
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.createNewContext(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.createNewContext(NativePipeline.java:2736)
    at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.createNewContext(Canvas3D.java:4895)
    at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.createNewContext(Canvas3D.java:2421)
    at javax.media.j3d.Renderer.doWork(Renderer.java:895)
    at javax.media.j3d.J3dThread.run(J3dThread.java:256)

DefaultRenderingErrorListener.errorOccurred:
CONTEXT_CREATION_ERROR: Renderer: Error creating Canvas3D graphics context
graphicsDevice = D3DGraphicsDevice[screen=0]
canvas = javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D[canvas0,0,0,240x217]
Java 3D ERROR : wglGetExtensionsStringARB not support !
 - Zadan� proced�ra sa nena�la.


Fallback to use standard ChoosePixelFormat.
Java 3D ERROR : OpenGL 1.2 or better is required (GL_VERSION=1.1)
Java Result: 1
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

No, if what you are saying is true then it wouldn't say

```
Java 3D ERROR : OpenGL 1.2 or better is required (GL_VERSION=1.1)
```

but your OpenGL version is defenitly 1.1 even if its updated if you
nought a new one then I think or that they scammed you or you need to get
a new OpenGL card

you see the problem is in the pixelformat so obviously there is a problem in your card

**Fallback to use standard ChoosePixelFormat.**

```
Fallback to use standard ChoosePixelFormat. 
Java 3D ERROR : OpenGL 1.2 or better is required (GL_VERSION=1.1) 
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue for about a year, but only on jre 1.7+, I just discovered it was because I was using the following (very bad) code on the visible JFrame of the Canvas3D

```
jframe.removeNotify();
jframe.setUndecorated(true);
jframe.addNotify();
```

So perhaps other mechanisms that alter the jframe's graphics will drop out this oblique error message.

for example this answer was simply trying to put the JFrame on a screen that didn't exist and got the same bad driver version message

[Help debugging GL_VERSION error in a Java3d application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827514/help-debugging-gl-version-error-in-a-java3d-application)